# how to increase Size of Linear Layout

Tags: java, android-studio

How to increase size of linear layout by On click button in the menu... android studio

I did this but it didn't work:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();

  if (id == R.id.Larger){

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.asdf);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();

    params.height = ++params.height;
    params.width = ++params.width;
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
  }

  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Here my Layout:**

[image: Layout activity]

Comment: Please post your layout (xml).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is increasing the value of height and width but in very small proportions,

Try this:

```
if (id == R.id.Larger){

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.asdf);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();

    params.height = params.height + 100;
    params.width = params.width + 100;
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I want to increase scale by each button click like what we done at Text View because my Linear Layout contains scroll view and number of text views

Comment: I upload it as screenshot I couldn't write it here

Comment: I can't see your screenshot, but its ok. Please describe me your layout hierarchy. Example: LinearLayout -> ScrollView -> textView.

Comment: <RelativeLayout
    >


    <LinearLayout
>

        <ScrollView
>

            <LinearLayout


                <LinearLayout
>

                    <TextView

                        />

                    <TextView
 />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
>

                    <TextView
 />

                    <TextView
/>


                </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: You want to increase ONLY the size of the Linear Layout view (R.id.asdf)? or another view too like textview,...?

Comment: I want to increase size of 2 text views by increasing Linear layout size

Comment: <LinearLayout > <TextView /> <TextView /> </LinearLayout>  by increasing linear layout all its content increase.

Comment: Can I find way to increase all text views size with one code instead.not as seperat identifier.

Comment: if you want to increase all the textview size too, you need to create all dynamically.